# Ubuntu Server 19.10 Grub install fail

Tags: dual-boot

I just downloaded 19.10. Turned that into a USB bootable flash. 
I am reinstalling on the SD drive, which already had Kali, and Windows 10 dual boot working well. 
Now after in attempting to reformat the Kali ext4 drive and reinstalling the bootable to be the dual boot for Ubuntu and Windows 10 bootable. I get the following error to fail the installation. How do we fix this?

```
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```